# how to generate logs in separate file when starting the appium server programmatically

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios, appium-desktop

With this code appium logs are printed in console, how to generate appium logs in a separate file.

public class TestBaseclass {
static AppiumDriverLocalService appiumService;

```
@BeforeClass
public static void startserver() throws Exception {
      appiumService = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
        appiumService.start();
}

@AfterClass
public static void stopServer() throws Exception {
    
    System.out.println("Stop appium service");
    appiumService.stop();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Configures the appium server to write log to the given file.
 *
 * @param logFile A file to write log to.
 * @return A self reference.
 */
@Override
public AppiumServiceBuilder withLogFile(File logFile) {
    return super.withLogFile(logFile);
}
```

https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/service/local/AppiumServiceBuilder.java

AppiumServiceBuilder expose a method called withLogFile() that will write the logs into a given file.